# Use of "To" in a sentence?

Tags: grammar

This might be a very basic question. I saw following sentence in a dictionary. Emphasis mine.

> "defense portfolio could be the carrot **to dangle** before him"

I could not justify the use of "To" before dangle. I think the correct sentence should be

> "defense portfolio could be the carrot **dangling** before him"

Could you please explain which sentence should be the correct one? and why?

Comment: @NVZ Don't think so.  That's a question about which verbs license which verbal form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have run across an infinitive of purpose. The sentence

> The defence portfolio could be the carrot **to dangle before him**.

means the the position is to be considered as a possible incentive (i.e., that would be the purpose of offering the position). The sentence

> The defence portfolio could be the carrot **dangling before him**.

means that it's possible that an incentive is being offered and it's the position mentioned.